# Validation using bootstrap tooltip and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in which, a user enters all the required data.

When user enters invalid data (such has entering a digit in his/her name field) a tooltip should be genereted over the field .

How to achieve this feature? My form looks like this.

1. first name
2. lastname
3. phone number
4. email
5. department 6)date of birth etc.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything yourself first?

Comment: Yes, of course . but using div tags .

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your first name input id is "first_name" and you want to make a length validation.
You should make a javascript function with your validation example:

```
function valid_first_name() {
    if (($("#first_name").val().length > 3) && ($("#first_name").val().length < 20)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#first_name').on('blur', function() {
        if (!valid_first_name()) {
            $("#first_name_error").text("invalid name").css('color', '#FF0000').show();
        }
    });
});
```

and your html :

```
<div id="first_name_error" style="display:none"></div>
<input type="text" id="first_name">
```

This is just a basic example which make a length validation on blur  .